# cannot pass grading but no issue in stress test_Coursera Algorithmic toolbox: Programming Assignment 1: Maximum Pairwise Product

Tags: python

I wrote the code below but cannot figure out why I cannot pass the coursera grading but found no issue in stress test. the grader output is :
**Failed case #4/17: Wrong answer
(Time used: 0.04/5.00, memory used: 22884352/2147483648.)**

```
# cannot pass coursera grading, don't know why

def pairwise_product_self(numbers):
    n = len(numbers)
    max_i = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if numbers[i] > max_i:
            max_i = numbers[i]
            global max_i_idx 
            max_i_idx = i

    del numbers[max_i_idx]
    max_j = 0
    for j in range(n - 1):
        if numbers[j] > max_j:
            max_j = numbers[j]

    return max_i * max_j



if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print(pairwise_product_self(numbers))
```

Comment: Can there be negative numbers?

Comment: The question defines input will be a sequence of non-negative integers

Comment: What's the original question prompt?

Comment: It's the maximum pairwise products problem. input a sequence of non-negative intergers, and output the maximum product of any 2 numbers in the sequence.

Comment: Are you allowed to multiply the biggest number with itself?

Comment: It looks like `max_i_idx` doesn't get initialized if the list is all zeros. What if you initialize `max_i_idx = 0` before the first loop?

Comment: Negative. It has to be 2 different number in the array. if the biggest number shows up twist then yes.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, that's the problem. I got it fixed after initialize max_i_idx = 0